# Android Development. Is there a way to send a notification or variable from Google maps application to my own application

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation, location

I have coded an application in android studio designed for a take away to view their drivers on a map as part of my thesis. If a driver is signed in an admin can click on their name and view them on google maps.

I am using firebase, basically the driver constantly uploads their coordinates to firebase and the admin uses them to view their whereabouts on Google maps.

From the admin side I want to designate an address(from a list of stored addresses in database) to a driver. This should then launch satnav or google maps on the drivers phone locating them to the address. When the driver reaches the address I want the admin to get a notification of some sort with a timestamp to say they reached the destination and how long it took.

SO... if i am to launch google maps from the drivers phone is it possible for me to use the info from it in my program to send a notification that they arrived at the destination or will I have to code my own sat nav into the program?

Or any ideas on a smart way to do this before I start coding are appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Your app should use a geofence to determine when the driver arrives at the destination: https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Comment: Could this confuse things if another driver passes that geofence on the way to another job? or can I set a geofence specific to the driver that was designated the job? cheers for the reply

Comment: You would send each job to a specific driver, probably with a FCM push notification. Your app can then notify the user of a job, and use the data sent in the FCM push notification to set up the geofence and also launch Google Maps for navigation.

Comment: So then the geofence would only be relevant to that driver? even though there is other drivers using the same app?